# How do I do TripleDES encryption in python3 using a pre-defined key and IV?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, tripledes

Because of legacy C#.NET code, I cannot change the key and the IV. They simply are what they are. But I cannot seem to find a way to do what I need to do. I tried this...

```
strToEncrypt = "Please encrypt me."
ivStr = "AStringOfIV="
keyStr = "aKeyOfSomeKindThat+IWillNotShare"

cipher = DES3.new(keyStr, DES3.MODE_CFB, IV=ivStr)
encryptedStr = cipher.iv + cipher.encrypt(strToEncrypt)
```

This told me "IV must be 8 bytes long."

Mine isn't and it can't be. So apparently this won't work. I also tried this:

```
m=hashlib.md5()
print(sys.getsizeof(iv))
m.update(bytes(keyStr, 'UTF-8'))
k = pyDes.triple_des(m.digest(),pyDes.CBC,IV=iv,padmode=pyDes.PAD_PKCS5)
encryptedStr = k.encrypt(strToEncrypt)
```

This told me "Invalid Initial Value (IV), must be a multiple of 8 bytes".

I tweaked the ivStr variable, checking it with getsizeof() as shown above, just to see what would happen:

```
ivStr = "AStringOfIV===="
```

I got the same message, "Invalid Initial Value (IV), must be a multiple of 8 bytes". But... it is. Now what?

I tried passing it in as bytes directly, both with the original ivStr and with the one that was 64 bytes, with extra equals signs.

```
k = pyDes.triple_des(
    keyStr,
    mode=pyDes.CBC,
    IV=bytes(ivStr, 'UTF-8'),
    pad=None,
    padmode=pyDes.PAD_PKCS5
)
encryptedStr = k.encrypt(strToEncrypt)
```

I got the same message, "Invalid Initial Value (IV), must be a multiple of 8 bytes". It is I tell you!

I tried pyDes.CBC and pyDes.ECB, wondering if somehow that would make a difference. None I could see.

---

Per a suggestion from @ShadowRanger in the comments below, I switched my initial code to add `b64decode` and `b64encode` like this:

```
pyDes.triple_des(m.digest(),pyDes.CBC,IV=base64.b64decode(ivStr),padmode=pyDes.PAD_PKCS5)
encryptedStr = base64.b64encode(k.encrypt(strToEncrypt))
```

That did remove the 8-bytes error I was getting and produced a string result, however, the string result does not match the result the C# program produces, so I am still not at the finish line yet.

---

For reference, if it helps, the C#.NET decrypt code that will be used against my encrypted string (and the old C#.NET code to encrypt it in the first place) is here:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace encryption
{
    class Program
    {
        const string IV = "AStringOfIV=";
        const string Key = "aKeyOfSomeKindThat+IWillNotShare";

        public static string Encrypt(string data)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            ICryptoTransform transform = tdes.CreateEncryptor(Convert.FromBase64String(Key), Convert.FromBase64String(IV));
            byte[] result = transform.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            string encrypted = BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-", "");
            return encrypted;
        }

        public static string Decrypt(string data)
        {
            byte[] result = StringToByteArray(data);
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            ICryptoTransform transform = tdes.CreateDecryptor(Convert.FromBase64String(Key), Convert.FromBase64String(IV));
            byte[] originalBytes = transform.TransformFinalBlock(result, 0, result.Length);
            string original = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(originalBytes);
            return original;
        }

        public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
        {
            int NumberChars = hex.Length / 2;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars];
            using (var sr = new System.IO.StringReader(hex))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i++)
                {
                    string thisByte = new string(new char[2] { (char)sr.Read(), (char)sr.Read() });
                    bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(thisByte, 16);
                }
            }
            return bytes;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Encrypt("397854"));
            Console.WriteLine(Encrypt("397786"));
            Console.WriteLine(Encrypt("70001948"));
            Console.WriteLine(Encrypt("70001890"));

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The code above, when run as a console application, produces the following results, which I need to duplicate in python3:

```
4B7389BB6DFE3AC7
39C739D51AC4FD13
BEB55BBC9430B83583E3E5E4E6C3799E
FD66F55347E715560C963B0EA181FB50
```

---

So, **how do I do TripleDES encryption in python3 using a pre-defined key and IV?**

If you can offer me any useful assistance, it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What a strange error message. There is no IV for ECB. CBC expects an IV of exactly the block size which is 8 bytes for DES/TripleDES. CFB expects an IV of exactly the segment size which is smaller or equal to the block size. For CTR the IV is smaller or equal to the block size and if it is smaller it is called a nonce and the remaining bits up to the block size are the counter. Anyway...show your C# with working examples of key and IV and then we might be able to help. Now it is just guessing.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have added the C#.NET code for reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the equals padding, I strongly suspect your IV is base64 encoded. Perhaps the original API expected to receive it base64 encoded? If you do `base64.b64decode("AStringOfIV=")` it produces a length 8 IV, `b'\x01+k\x8ax\x0e|\x85'`, which may get the behavior you want.

Comment: thanks! After making the change, the 8-byte error went away and I am now getting a string result. However, the string I get doesn't match the one in the legacy code (which I've added above). Any additional suggestions?

Comment: @gcdev: Based on your C# code, the same applies to the key (it's also base64). The data appears to be assumed to be a hex string representing raw bytes. Beyond that, I can't tell what mode C# defaults to (CBC, CFB, OFB, CTR, GCM, etc.), etc., so I'm not sure if you chose the right mode.

Comment: The hex part was the part I was missing! THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're using the correct encoding (Base64) for every value and correct mode of operation (CBC).

This is the python code that works for me:

```
import pyDes
import base64

strToEncrypt = "Please encrypt me."
ivStr = "AStringOfIV="
keyStr = "aKeyOfSomeKindThat+IWillNotShare"

k = pyDes.triple_des(
    base64.b64decode(keyStr),
    mode=pyDes.CBC,
    IV=base64.b64decode(ivStr),
    padmode=pyDes.PAD_PKCS5
)
encryptedStr = k.encrypt(strToEncrypt)

k = pyDes.triple_des(
    base64.b64decode(keyStr),
    mode=pyDes.CBC,
    IV=base64.b64decode(ivStr),
    padmode=pyDes.PAD_PKCS5
)
decryptedStr = k.decrypt(encryptedStr)
```

---

Please note that this code is not secure due to many issues:

- The IV is static, but must be unpredictable for CBC mode. The IV is not supposed to be secret. We usually prepend it to the ciphertext during encryption and slice it off before decryption.
- Triple DES has a small block size and the protocol you're using might be vulnerable to Sweet32 or similar attacks.
- You're not using any kind of authentication. That way you will not be able to detect whether there was any (malicious) change of the ciphertext along the way. CBC mode is partially malleable, so if you're using this for anything serious, the receiver must validate the decrypted message so that it fully conforms to a very strict structure. Instead I suggest the use of AES-GCM or at least the addition of a message authentication code like HMAC-SHA256 through an encrypt-then-MAC scheme.
- Your C# code uses defaults for mode of operation and padding. This is tricky because defaults may change in future .Net versions which might break your code. Always qualify what options you're using.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! The C# encryption code above, with input "397854" produces output "4B7389BB6DFE3AC7". Your python code, with the same input, produces "b'Ks\x89\xbbm\xfe:\xc7'". I tried to decode to utf-8 ("can't decode byte 0xe6") and ascii ("can't decode byte 0xe6") and ISO-8859-1 ("8æ[I[\"). How do I get the same results as the C# code?

Comment: Oh wow. I got it now. k.encrypt(strToEncrypt).hex() THANK YOU!!